# codeName one : full duplex conversation

Tags: codenameone

I have a camera with a microphone and a speaker.

I want to make a full duplex audio communication between the browser of a terminal device and this camera.

Is it possible with CodeName One?
If so, can I have a tutorial?

Comment: Hi  sorry I forgot to greet before posting

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular please read [about if you should ask for tutorials here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Some folks consider the greetings here to be superfluous and will remove them.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a tutorial for this. If you want to use a browser within the app to do this you can use the `BrowserComponent` notice that this won't behave the same on the simulator and the device.